# Asus EEE PC 1005HA battery not being detected

Tags: laptop, netbook, battery, eee-pc

My EEE PC's battery is not being detected since this morning. The battery indicator doesn't turn on, `Power Options` in Windows doesn't detect a battery either. Apart from removing the battery and plugging it back again (which I already did), what can I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something else to try:

1) Start the Eee PC up with the battery in and the AC adapter plugged in
2) Open up Power Options in Windows. In my case, the battery reads 100%
3) Remove the battery
4) Wait a minute or two and plug the battery back in

Doing this will hopefully make the hardware recognize the battery again, and it should appear as discharged in the Power Options.

It seems that many people are having this issue, which comes down to a defective battery. If the above solution doesn't work, you might just have to RMA the laptop.

[Solution source](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?SLanguage=en-us&id=20090717015923875&board_id=20&model=Eee%20PC%201005HA&page=4&count=60)

Comment: I had to RMA the laptop, and got a replacement. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold the power button when turning on the Eee PC 1005ha.

Problem with this is that the battery still can't be read by the netbook configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Most ASUS EEE PC have a reset button (use a pin) at the bottom. Might be hidden under some sticker though. Try it.

In the image below you'll see the tiny hole at the right-hand underside.

[image: underside of chassis]

If this doesn't help, disconnect all power sources (AC adapter AND battery), press the power button to completely discharge the EEE PC, reconnect power and try again.